# Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font ''

Tags: reactjs

for some reason the url for the font is empty as I can see in the network tab.

Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

it is not about using http, because it is a font inside the application itself.
this is fine when I run the application locally.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Open-Sans-Bold;
  src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure is this the font that leads to the error?

Comment: Can you show the original error?

Comment: The error is in the title.

Comment: I just need to know why the font url is sent blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my issue was the font size. I had a limitation in webpack loader. so it was coming empty. but the error message was so poor and confusing.

Comment: facing exact similar issue. what do I need to change?